# Difference between bake and roast

Tags: oven

First question-
If the receipe says to bake without mentioning to preheat, readymade base for instance, should I preheat the oven?

Second question-
Is the receipe asks to roast, bell pepper for instance, does it means to preheat and bake? Or shall I just use at microwave mode??? Pls help

Comment: See also [What is the difference between roasting, baking, and broasting?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/what-is-the-difference-between-roasting-baking-and-broasting)

Comment: Baking in the oven. Roast with fire

Answer (score 5):

Any recipe which calls for you to bake, roast, or otherwise cook at a particular temperature, is expecting you to preheat the cooker to the specified temperature before adding the food, unless it specifically says otherwise.

"Roast" or "bake" never mean "microwave". If a recipe wants you to use the microwave, it'll say that. (There are, of course, things you can choose to do in a microwave or in some other cooker, like melting butter; that's up to you.)